# How to disable auto logging using Serilog in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, serilog

I would know if there's a way to disable auto-logging using `Serilog`.

I installed it and the `sink` to handle logging using MSSqlServer.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=tcp:{ServerAddress};Initial Catalog={DBName};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={Username};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
          "sinkOptionsSection": {
            "tableName": "App_Logs",
            "autoCreateSqlTable": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  // ...other configs
}
```

then this is my config in `Progam.cs`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
        });
```

In `Startup.cs` (now commented because i thought it was the cause of the auto loggin but also commenting it it auto-writes records on db):

```cs
// enables Serilog's HTTP request logging. 
// IMPORTANT: it won't log anything that appears *before* it in the pipeline, 
// so be sure to add it *before* UseEndpoints(), UseMvc(), UseSpa() and so on.
// app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();  <------ i thought it was the cause of the auto loggin but also commenting it it auto-writes records on db
```

The logging action:

```
public MVCBaseController(
    ILogger<TController> logger,
    ...)
{
    Logger = logger;
    // ...
}

public ILogger<TController> Logger { get; }
// ...

protected void LogInformation(string message)
{
    string controllerName = ControllerContext?.ActionDescriptor?.ControllerName ?? string.Empty;
    string actionName = ControllerContext?.ActionDescriptor?.ActionName ?? string.Empty;
    string names = 
        $"[{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName) ? $"{controllerName}" : "Controller name not found")}" 
        + $"{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName) ? $".{actionName}]" : "]")}";

    Logger.LogInformation($"{names}\n{message}");
}
```

It works but when i check the table i see a lot of records in addition to mine:
[image: db_result]

is there a way to tell Serilog to log only my handled logs?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there a way to tell Serilog to log only my handled logs? Thank you!

Yes, there is. You can control which logs will go to the sinks with `MinimumLevel` configuration property.

> *The `MinimumLevel` configuration property can be set to a single value or, levels can be overridden per logging source.* ~ [Serilog Configuration Readme](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#minimumlevel-levelswitches-overrides-and-dynamic-reload)

Single value:

```
{
  "Serilog: {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Object with overrides per namespace:

```
{
  "Serilog":{
    "MinimumLevel":{
      "Default":"Information",
      "Override":{
        "YOUR.PROJECT.NAMESPACE":"Debug",
        "Microsoft":"Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore":"Warning",
        "MongoDB.Driver":"Warning",
        "System":"Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `YOUR.PROJECT.NAMESPACE` with the name of your project namespace and from now on only warnings from namespaces above will go to your SQL Server sink and debug level logs from your project.

##### Restrict sink to minimum level log

There is also a possibility to restrict a sink, such as your SQL server, to a minimum level of logs. For that use `restrictedToMinimumLevel` property of `Args`:

```
{
  "Serilog":{
    "Using":[
      "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel":"Information",
    "WriteTo":[
      {
        "Name":"MSSqlServer",
        "Args":{
          "connectionString":"Server=tcp:{ServerAddress};Initial Catalog={DBName};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={Username};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
          "sinkOptionsSection":{
            "tableName":"App_Logs",
            "autoCreateSqlTable":true,
            "restrictedToMinimumLevel":"Warning"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Configuration above will log Warning level logs to SQL Server.

And one last note, if you switched to Serilog and are not using the built-in ASP.NET Core logging, you can safely remove the previous `Logging` section from your `appsettings.json` file/s. These will have no effect on Serilog logging:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked with this config on `appsettings`:
`"MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Project.Namespace": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },` i put Warning instead of Information on the Microsoft property because otherwise it still kept writing some records

Comment: replace "Microsoft":"Information" with "Microsoft":"Debug", it works good.